# How to read the next line in Java without moving the pointer?

Tags: java

I have a text file with thousands of lines and I need to check the content of the next line from the current line to take one action or another. I have tried to do it with BufferedReader, LineNumberReader and Scanner, but when I put the code to read the next line, the "pointer" changes:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

This is what actually happens to me:

```
line = readLine(); // line = Line 1, pointer at Line 1
nextLine = readNextLine() // nextLine = Line 2, pointer at Line 2

// check the content
if(nextLine.equals(...))
...

// continue reading
line = readLine(); // line = Line 3, pointer at Line 3
```

And this is what I want to do:

```
line = readLine(); // line = Line 1, pointer at Line 1
nextLine = readNextLine() // nextLine = Line 2, pointer at Line **1**


// check the content
if(nextLine.equals(...))
...

// continue reading
line = readLine(); // line = Line **2**, pointer at Line **2**
```

Is there any possible way to do that?

Comment: Is there anything specific you´d like to do with this specific line and the `Scanner`? If not, allways keeping the value of the current line and the previous line in seperate variables would be a solution here.

Comment: You can use the mark(..) method and then reset() to do what you want. e.g. reader.mark(10000);line=reader.readLine();.....;reader.reset(). This way you should get the same line twice if necessary.